Is my battery dead after just a year and a half?
so here's the situation. My battery is 1,5 year old. Last week my car (Honda Civic 2015) wouldn't start. No lights, no radio, nothing. I had it jumpstarted and drove around for 45min. After 45, I turned the car off, went to the grocery and when I came back, the car started fine.
The car assistance guy who jumpstarted it told me that this hapenned because my car is sitting for too long and I don't drive long enough with it. But the next day, the car won't start again. The voltage on the battery is 1.5V.
I don't use the car that often but last month I made a one month roadtrip where I would drive 4-6 hours everyday with AC on high. Could that have influenced the battery life somehow? Is there something draining the battery when the car is off or is my battery somehow dead after 1.5 year?
Thanks a lot!

1.5V means the battery is quite dead.
I'd suggest jump starting it, and then check the voltage across the battery with the engine running.  It should be 14 to 14.5 Volts and this shows the alternator is working.   I suspect alternator is okay, because this is enough to keep the engine running even with a weak battery.
Batteries are consumables - but an 18 month lifespan is half what you'd expect.Check the battery's label for a manufacture date.  It might be older than you think.


I had it jumpstarted and drove around for 45min. After 45, I turned the car off, went to the grocery and when I came back, the car started fine.

A jump start provides only very little charge. So if you started it and successfully drove 45 minutes, most of the energy had to come from the alternator. A single jump start does not provide enough charge for driving 45 minutes. Therefore, the alternator is good.
Your battery is probably dead. 1.5 years is not a good lifetime, I have an 8-year old battery that's still going strong. These things can happen, sometimes some products have a lower-than-expected lifetime.

I don't use the car that often

This could provide some evidence for the short lifetime. A car has parasitic draws. Thus, you should use it for a good long drive at least once a week. If it sits more than a week, or of the weekly drive is short, the battery won't be maintained at full charge. What lead-acid batteries don't like is discharge. Even one deep discharge can kill a battery or severely reduce its lifetime at least, and keeping it partially discharged for a period of 1.5 years can also shorten its lifetime enough that it has a lifetime of only those 1.5 years.
Unfortunately, for your car usage patterns, you have to keep buying batteries often, or buy a maintenance charger, or modify your car usage patterns by driving more often.
If you choose the maintenance charger approach, remember that it has to be a float charger (13.5 - 13.8 volts), and it may be useful to have a timer which provides only few hours of maintenance charge per day. Constantly keeping a battery at float voltage kills it in 5 years, which is longer than the 1.5 years you got, but shorter than optimal. By limiting maintenance charge for only few hours per day, you may get as good as 10 year lifetime, assuming you bought a quality battery.
In lead-acid batteries, quality matters a lot. No-name manufacturers create batteries that have a short lifetime.
